# What is a better way of handling this type of issue?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array

I'm sort of new to iOS development using Swift.  So, I might be missing a simple solution in Swift that I'm not aware of. 
 I am working on a tvOS app where I display a list of video content that the user can select from.  The app also contains a settings tab that allows the user to configure 5 different types of settings.  Once they select a specific category, it displays a new table view with the corresponding options which are in the options array.  This is where the "issue" is that I need help.

I have this struct which I'm using as a singleton:

```
struct BMUserSettings
{
    internal static var shared = BMUserSettings()
    var categories = [String]()
    var options = [[String]]()
    var currOptionsSelected: [Int] = [0,0,0,0,0] // This array corresponds to the categories array.  It tells us what option within that group was selected.
    init()
    {
        self.categories = ["Brand", "Environment","UI Language", "Playback Language", "Geo Location Permission"]

        let brandOptionsGroup: [String] = ["CTV", "CTVHUB", "TSN", "Snackable", "RDS", "CP24", "BNN", "CTVNews", "Crave", "BRAVO", "E_BRAND", "SE", "VIDIQA"]
        let environmentOptionsGroup: [String] = ["Staging", "Prod"]
        let uiLanguageOptionsGroup: [String] = ["en", "fr"]
        let playbackLanguageOptionsGroup: [String] = ["en", "fr"]
        let geoLocationOptionsGroup: [String] = ["Allow", "Don't Allow"]

        options.append(brandOptionsGroup)
        options.append(environmentOptionsGroup)
        options.append(uiLanguageOptionsGroup)
        options.append(playbackLanguageOptionsGroup)
        options.append(geoLocationOptionsGroup)
    }

    // MARK: - Custom Methods
    func displayUserSettings() -> String
    {
        let displayText: String = "Brand=\(options[0][currOptionsSelected[0]])     Environment=\(options[1][currOptionsSelected[1]])     UI Language=\(options[2][currOptionsSelected[2]])     Playback Language=\(options[3][currOptionsSelected[3]])     Geo Location=\(options[4][currOptionsSelected[4]])"
        return displayText
    }

    // MARK: - User Defaults
    func saveToUserDefaults()
    {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected, forKey: "currentoptions")
    }

    func loadFromUserDefaults(){
        if let currentOptionsSelected = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "currentoptions") as? [Int]{
            BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected = currentOptionsSelected
        }
        else{
            BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected = [0,0,0,0,0]
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the "currOptionsSelected" integer array is holding the option that the user selected for each of the categories.  For example, if the user chooses the brand "Snackable", then the first element of the currOptionsSelected array will hold a 3 as a value.

I'm saving and loading the currOptionsSelected to/from UserDefaults so that I know what the user's current settings are.

The problem with this approach is:
1) Even if I know the index of the specific option that the user chose, I will still need a set if if-else or switch conditions to make sure I can actually get the correct string value from the corresponding "options" array
2) If any other developer needs to add categories and corresponding options, then they need to make sure they keep everything in order
3) I just don't know if this is the best way of handling this type of issue

What is a better way of doing this?

---

Here's how I'm trying to use it in a table view:

```
import UIKit

final class BMSettingsViewController: UIViewController
{
    // MARK: - Instance Variables
    private static let reuseIdentifier = String(describing: BMContentCell.self)
    private let tableview = UITableView(backgroundColor: .white, autoResizingMask: false)
    private let tabBarBannerHeight: CGFloat = 150
    private var selectedCategoryIndex: Int = 0
    private var settingsDetailVC: BMDetailSettingsViewController?
    private var categoryNames: [String] = [String]()
    private var categoryOptions: [String] = [String]()

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle Methods
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        categoryNames = BMCategory.allValues
        categoryOptions = BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected.map { $0.value }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool)
    {
        BMUserSettings.shared.saveToUserDefaults()
    }

    override func loadView()
    {
        super.loadView()
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview.register(BMUserSettingsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: BMSettingsViewController.reuseIdentifier)
        displayContent()
    }

    // MARK: - Custom Methods
    private func displayContent()
    {
        view.addSubview(tableview)
        tableview.anchor(
            top: self.view.topAnchor,
            leading: self.view.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor,
            trailing: self.view.trailingAnchor,
            padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: tabBarBannerHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        )
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableView Datasource & Delegate Extension
extension BMSettingsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        return "Select an option below to configure it's settings..."
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return categoryNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BMSettingsViewController.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BMUserSettingsCell
        cell.configureCell(categoryName: categoryNames[indexPath.row], optionDetailDescription: categoryOptions[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let selectedCategory = categoryNames[indexPath.row]
        settingsDetailVC = BMDetailSettingsViewController()
        guard let settingsVC = settingsDetailVC else {return}
        settingsVC.options = BMUserSettings.shared.options[BMCategory.init(rawValue: selectedCategory)!]!
        settingsVC.delegate = self
        settingsVC.selectedCategoryIndex = indexPath.row
        BMViewControllerManager.shared.getTopViewController()?.present(settingsVC, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 120
    }
}

// MARK: - Protocol Extension
extension BMSettingsViewController: OptionsSelector
{
    func didFinishSelectingOption(selectedCategoryIndex: Int, selectedOptionIndex: Int)
    {
        self.selectedCategoryIndex = selectedCategoryIndex
//      BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected[self.selectedCategoryIndex] = selectedOptionIndex
    }
}
```

Here's the settings detail controller that lists just the options within that specific category:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Protocol (used to notify Settings view controller when an option was selected)
protocol OptionsSelector
{
    func didFinishSelectingOption(selectedCategoryIndex: Int, selectedOptionIndex: Int)
}

final class BMDetailSettingsViewController: UIViewController
{
    // MARK: - Instance Variables
    private let cellId = "cellId"
    private let tabBarBannerHeight: CGFloat = 150   
    private var selectedOptionIndex: Int = 0
    private let tableview = UITableView(backgroundColor: .white, autoResizingMask: false)

    var options: [String] = [String]()
    var selectedCategoryIndex: Int = 0
    var delegate: OptionsSelector?

    // MARK: - View Life Cycle Methods
    override func loadView()
    {
        super.loadView()
        self.tableview.dataSource = self
        self.tableview.delegate = self
        self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        displayContent()
    }

    // MARK: - Custom Methods
    private func displayContent()
    {
        view.addSubview(tableview)
        tableview.anchor(
            top: self.view.topAnchor,
            leading: self.view.leadingAnchor,
            bottom: self.view.bottomAnchor,
            trailing: self.view.trailingAnchor,
            padding: UIEdgeInsets(top: tabBarBannerHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        )
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableView Datasource & Delegate Extension
extension BMDetailSettingsViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? { return "Select an option below..." }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return options.count }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style:  .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(options[indexPath.row])"
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        BMViewControllerManager.shared.getTopViewController()?.dismiss(animated: true)
        self.selectedOptionIndex = indexPath.row
        self.delegate?.didFinishSelectingOption(selectedCategoryIndex: self.selectedCategoryIndex, selectedOptionIndex: self.selectedOptionIndex)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Make `currOptionsSelected` an array of String so you know the categories instantly. Even better, make it a Set, not an Array. Even better, define the categories as an enum.

Comment: Can you give me a snippet of what you mean?

Comment: What is array `options` for?

Comment: options holds the individual options for each of the categories.  It's a multi-dimensional array...

Comment: This way you would solve 2) I would probably move to a dictionary structure. `var options = [OptionsKey, [String]]`. I would make a `enum OptionsKey: String { case brandOptionsGroup, environmentOptionsGroup, etc}`.  Accessing that dictionary would be something like `let array = options[.brandOptionsGroup]`
Adding another category won't be an issue.

Comment: @matt Even better, make it dictionary with meaningfully named keys, whose mapped values give the selection for that kind of setting. Though I wonder, is there meaningful difference storing one value in userdefaults which is a dict (with its own keyed structure), vs storing its key/value pairs as independent values in userdefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create an `enum Category`,

```
enum Category: String {
    case brand = "Brand"
    case environment = "Environment"
    case uiLanguage = "UI Language"
    case playbackLanguage = "Playback Language"
    case geoLocationPermission = "Geo Location"
}
```

Next,

1. Create `options` of type `[Category:[String]]`, `currOptionsSelected` of type `[Category:String]` and `defaultOptions` of type `[Category:String]`.
2. Also, instead of `displayUserSettings`, conform `struct BMUserSettings` to `CustomStringConvertible` and implement the `description` to return the relevant `String` value.
3. And, to create the *Singleton*, mark `init()` as `private`.
4. There is no need to create a separate `array` for `categories`.

So the whole `struct BMUserSettings` will be like,

```
struct BMUserSettings: CustomStringConvertible {
    static var shared = BMUserSettings()

    let options: [Category:[String]]
    let defaultOptions: [Category:String]
    var currOptionsSelected: [Category:String]
    let categories: [Category]

    private init() {
        options = [
            .brand : ["CTV", "CTVHUB", "TSN", "Snackable", "RDS", "CP24", "BNN", "CTVNews", "Crave", "BRAVO", "E_BRAND", "SE", "VIDIQA"],
            .environment : ["Staging", "Prod"],
            .uiLanguage : ["en", "fr"],
            .playbackLanguage : ["en", "fr"],
            .geoLocationPermission : ["Allow", "Don't Allow"]
        ]

        defaultOptions = self.options.mapValues{ $0.first! }
        currOptionsSelected = self.defaultOptions
        categories = [.brand, .environment, .uiLanguage, .playbackLanguage, .geoLocationPermission]
    }

    var description: String {
        return self.currOptionsSelected.reduce("") { (result, option) -> String in
            return "\(result) \(option.key.rawValue) = \(option.value)\n"
        }
    }

    // MARK: - User Defaults
    func saveToUserDefaults() {
        var dict = [String:String]()
        currOptionsSelected.forEach { dict[$0.key.rawValue] = $0.value }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(dict, forKey: "currentoptions")
    }

    mutating func loadFromUserDefaults() {
        if let currentOptionsSelected = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "currentoptions") as? [String:String] {
            var dict = [Category:String]()
            currentOptionsSelected.forEach {
                if let category = Category(rawValue: $0.key) {
                    dict[category] = $0.value
                }
            }
            self.currOptionsSelected = dict
        }
        else {
            self.currOptionsSelected = self.defaultOptions
        }
    }
}
```

Use it in the following way,

```
BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected[.brand] = "Snackable"
BMUserSettings.shared.saveToUserDefaults()
BMUserSettings.shared.loadFromUserDefaults()
print(BMUserSettings.shared)
BMUserSettings.shared.categories.forEach {
    print($0.rawValue, ":", BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected[$0]!)
}
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Thanks!

Comment: This solution has a flaw in it.  I'm getting the following error: "Simultaneous accesses to 0x100b53618, but modification requires exclusive access.".  It's happening at the else condition in loadFromUserDefaults()

Comment: Use `self.currOptionsSelected = self.defaultOptions` instead.

Comment: Actually, no... there is another issue.  The problem is that the category names are not in the same order that the currOptionsSelected are...essentially, I'm trying to get have them sync with each other but they are in different order.

Comment: You won’t need the category names in order with this approach. Here the data is stored in Dictionary form not as an Array.

Comment: I should explain myself better... I'm using the category enum's raw values in a table view.  But the problem is that I need to know what value was selected by looking in the currOptionsSelected dictionary.  Because they are not in the same order, the table view looks all messed up.  For example, Brand is showing up as "On" (which is the value for the Geo Location key).

Comment: Can you show how you're using the data in the tableView?

Comment: In my view controller here's where I get the list of all the category names and the options.  I'm trying to put them into arrays that correspond with each other.  For example, element 0 in each array should be for the Brand, element 1 in each array should be for the Geo Location setting etc...

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)
 {
  super.viewWillAppear(animated)
  categoryNames = BMCategory.allValues
  categoryOptions = BMUserSettings.shared.currOptionsSelected.map { $0.value }
  self.tableview.reloadData()
 }

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
 {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: BMSettingsViewController.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BMUserSettingsCell
  cell.configureCell(categoryName: categoryNames[indexPath.row], optionDetailDescription: categoryOptions[indexPath.row])
  return cell
 }

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
 {
  let selectedCategory = categoryNames[indexPath.row]
  settingsDetailVC = BMDetailSettingsViewController()
  guard let settingsVC = settingsDetailVC else {return}
  settingsVC.options = BMUserSettings.shared.options[BMCategory.init(rawValue: selectedCategory)!]!
  settingsVC.delegate = self
  settingsVC.selectedCategoryIndex = indexPath.row
  BMViewControllerManager.shared.getTopViewController()?.present(settingsVC, animated: true)
 }

Comment: Add this in the question not in the comments.

Comment: Done, I've added the details above.

Comment: I've updated the answer and added the `categories` array in the answer.

Comment: So you just added 2 lines? You declared a new categories variable that is an array of BMCategory enums and then set it's order?

Comment: @JFortYork Right. It'll define the expected order that you want to show in the tableView.

Comment: You are a genius!

Comment: I need to be able to iterate over categories using an index.  I can't use a ForEach in a cellForRowAt method since it's looking for a specific row/index